# Count items grouped by different section names

Tags: php, mysql

I have a db:

```
---------------------
| section | name    |
---------------------
| food    | steak   |
---------------------
| food    | chicken |
---------------------
| drink   | water   | 
---------------------
| food    | pork    | 
---------------------
| drink   | soda    | 
---------------------
| drink   | steak   | 
---------------------
```

I am trying to count the number of rows with each section. The problem is, I don't have static section names. I am trying to do it with one query.

Here is the result I am looking for:

```
-------------
| food  | 3 |
-------------
| drink | 3 |
-------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT section, COUNT(name) FROM table_name GROUP BY section
```